# Duas Contas Gerenciando a Mesma API do Google.

Tags: javascript, api, google

Existe alguma forma de duas contas distintas gerenciarem a mesma chave (App Key) do google através do console.developers.google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sim**. A chave pertence a um projeto. Um projeto pode possuir vários usuários, com distintas permissões associadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Funcionou!!! Obrigado!!!

Comment: @fba_pereira Não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar. =)